# How to increment the amount of documents shown in the Recent Document List

Tags: 11.04, document-management

How can i increment the amount of Recent Documents in the Recent Document List since 10 Items is very small for the kind of files i open in a day.

Am using Ubuntu Classic (No Effect)

Comment: Hi CYREX, I looked, and looked, and looked some more. But it seems that after 10.04 all workarounds were rendered useless. Perhaps you could submit a feature request? I would certainly vote for it.

Comment: Thank you Alan i too have looked a lot. Even got to the .gtkrc-2.0 file and searched several options for it. No luck. Most of the people want to either limit the amount (Come ON! is only 10 for crying out load) or remove the whole Recent document option (What the crap O.o)

Comment: I know, it's a little odd that you can't adjust it to your liking. I don't know if it's just me, but I feel like Ubuntu is being dumbed-down or over simplified at times.

Comment: Feel the same but we need to know that as of this version of Ubuntu, Ubuntu is morphing into something not quite finished. Unity is new and Gnome-shell (gnome3) is new as how KDE was new when the first 4.0 version came out. If anything there is several months to wait for Unity to give fruits, same for Gnome3. This option might be good to add to the Brainstorm ideas since Ubuntu i think is the only one giving this possibility to users. Anyway i also think the same as you mention

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, the number of the recent document list is hardcoded in Gnome and can't be changed afaik.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no longer using GNOME, so I can't test this, but I remember a .gtkrc config directive from my GNOME days:

gtk-recent-files-limit=x

where 'x' is the max number of MRU entries.

Comment: Negative. Already tried that.